# Can Bone Knights create bonecraft shields?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron, prestige-class

The Eberron handbook states that a bone knight is capable of creating bonecraft armor, and eventually even bonecraft weapons. Does this include shields as well? It only lists regular armor in the handbook.

> Bonecraft Armor (Ex): At 1st level, you learn to
>   make and wear the distinctive bonecraft armor used by
>   the order of bone knights. You can produce a suit of
>   bonecraft medium or heavy armor that would normally
>   be composed mostly of metal. The bonecraft armor has
>   the same cost and time to create as normal armor of
>   that type. It is possible to spend additional time and
>   money to produce spiked or masterwork bonecraft
>   armor (which may then be further enhanced through
>   magic). Only a character with this ability can effectively
>   wear bonecraft armor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: **No.**

Longer answer: There is nothing that either gives them the ability to craft shields, or that classifies shields as a "suit of armor". **However** it could be a reasonable houserule for following reasons:

- The DR wouldn't stack, nothing OP in there
- It fits thematically and reasonably well
- There is a a similar precedence in Craft skill, where both armour and shields fall under the same skill. Note that it doesn't make it RAW viable, just easier to rationalise houseruling

It may have been a conscious decision on the part of the game makers, as it grants an untyped bonus, which would stack, and be strong for Intimidate focused builds. However, I find that a marginal issue.

Comment: Houseruling it to be the same as its equivalent steel shield without rusting seems reasonable. Like you said, it shouldn't have any intimate or damage reduction properties.